# Python Multithreading returns Bad File Descriptor?

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

So, I am making a chat server (how original!), and I am using `multithreading` to handle data sending/recieving, alongside logging and (soon to be) server-sided commands. ANYhoo.. I run the server, all is good thus far. Run a client, Hey! It works! Relaunch the client and I get ;

```
Exception in thread Thread-5:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Users\Kuro\Desktop\PyChat\Server.py", line 51, in run
    s.listen(9999)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 224, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 170, in _dummy
    raise error(EBADF, 'Bad file descriptor')
error: [Errno 9] Bad file descriptor
```

on the server, but it still works. No errors on the client, yet. Run the client again, and this happens;
`[Errno 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it`. No server in/output.
Here's the server code:

```
import socket
import threading
import sys
import os
import time

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
IP = raw_input("IP to host the server on: ")
Port = 9340
dat = None
s.bind((IP,Port))

class recvdat(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, TID, TN):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.TID = TID
        self.TN = TN
    def run(self):
        global dat, conn
        while True:
            try:
                dat = conn.recv(1048)
            except:
                dat = None
                s.close()
                break
            if dat == "/exit" or None:
                s.close()
                break
            else:
                print dat
                chtlg.write(dat)
                dat = None


class senddat(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, TID, TN):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.TID = TID
        self.TN = TN
    def run(self):
        pass

class acconn(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, TID, TN):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.TID = TID
        self.TN = TN
    def run(self):
        global conn, act, ACTID
        s.listen(9999)
        conn, addr = s.accept()
        rdt = recvdat(2,"rdt")
        ACTID = ACTID+1
        act = acconn(ACTID,"act")
        act.start()
        rdt.start()
        #print "Client Connected with IP "+addr

cwd = os.getcwd()
chtlg = open(cwd+"/ChatLog",'a')
ACTID = 0

act = acconn(ACTID,"act")

act.start()

while True:
    time.sleep(2.5)
    pass
```

Yes, it is a *very* bad excuse of a multithreading program, however, it is very incomplete because I was buried in making the client, and I don't use classes or `multithreading` very often..

Any help at all would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel (*unless it's for learning*); Have you seen [chatserver.py](https://github.com/circuits/circuits/blob/master/examples/chatserver.py)

Comment: @JamesMills It's not exactly for learning, I was tasked with, just that, re-inventing the wheel while making improvements along the way. I feel a simplified version of `chatserver.py` would be of use to anyone who needs it, so they can actually understand it, not just blankly stare at it completely clueless, while keeping it lightweight and customizable, but, thanks anyway!

Comment: It's as lightweight as it's going to get I'm afraid; what don't you understand? Perhaps I can help in some way? I just don't have the time to debug  your multi-threaded I/O program right now; in short: Bad File Descriptor errors result from using file descriptors that are no longer valid and connected to anything; i.e: They're dead.

Comment: So you're saying it has to do with the client then, that it's not a server issue?

Comment: Well the error is coming from your server implmentation; but you likely have issues with both because doing Socket I/O is not really that trivial and there are many edge cases to take care of. Use a framework like [circuits](https://github.com/circuits/circuits) or [Twisted](https://github.com/twisted)